# spl_autoload_register searching in wrong directory/file

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I have placed the following code in my functions file (MyFunctions.php):

```
spl_autoload_register               
( 
    function( $Class )              
    { 
        $Class = str_replace ( "..", "", $Class );
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/phpsb/class library/' . $Class . '.php';
    }
);
```

But when I reference an class/object from my script, `spl_autoload_register` searches in the functions file in which it is defined, rather than class library directory:

```
Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsb/class library/FormClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\function library\MyFunctions.php
```

Comment: Are you following PSR-0?

Comment: I can see `class library/FormClass.php`: isn't that correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misread error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $className = (string) str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
        include_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $className . '.php');
});
```

This code supports namespaces and i'm supposing MyFunctions.php is in the same directory of your dinamically loaded PHP files.

Comment: Cheers. The reason it was failing was because I had renamed the directory the class and function directories reside in but forgot to update the include path inside spl_autoload_register.

Comment: @Nathan - So it couldn't find `C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsb/class library/FormClass.php` because it didn't exist, just like the error message says :) Not sure if you need certain rep but you should probably remove the question.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - Yes, but the warning isn't very clear! The message states that it is looking in the functions directory rather than the class directory. I can't see an option to delete the question.

Comment: Oh, I guess you need a minimum rep to remove your own questions. (What it *Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsb/class library/FormClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory* makes you think it's looking in your functions directory?)